# Decoding register data from our Solar Power system

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Python program which is accessing one of the devices on our Solar Power system.  I can read the registers which are supposed to conform to the SunSpec conventions.  I have been able to decode most of the values, but I'm stuck on decoding the TCP_Address and gateway which are sourced from these two registers:

```
TCP Address:
reg 22 value 49320 in HEX 0xc0a8
reg 23 value 64 in HEX 0x40
Gataway Address:
reg 24 value 49320 in HEX 0xc0a8
reg 25 value 1 in HEX 0x1
```

the documentation says that the format for these values is "uint32", which I interpret to mean unsigned 32 bit integer.  The result of decoding should be something like 192.168.0.?.

Can anyone assist to understand how to convert the above to that format in Python? Thanks...RDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
def Decode_TCPIP(reg1,reg2):
#    print("Reg1 = "+ reg1 + " Reg2 = " + reg2)
    UpperMask = 0xff00
    LowerMask = 0x00ff
    First = (reg1 & UpperMask)/256
    Second = (reg1 & LowerMask)
    Third = (reg2 & UpperMask)/256
    Forth = (reg2 & LowerMask)

    return First, Second, Third, Forth
```

the returned values are then the four digits in the IP address....RDK

Answer (score 0):

I would say that

```
0xc0 0xa8 (0x00) 0x01
```

is 192.168.0.1, your gateway. Seems you've just missed to note that both registers are 16 bits so you've neglected the high byte..

Comment: Yes, I figured it out but then forgot to post my solution.  I will do it now